# Android: Should I avoid self-written methods in Commonsware's WakefulIntentservice?

Tags: java, android, wakelock, commonsware-cwac

In my application, I've got CommosWare's `WakefulIntentservice`. From the `doWakefulWork` method I call a couple of self-written methods. For example:

```
@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent arg0) {
    exampleMethod();
}

private void exampleMethod() {
    //Stuff
}
```

It keeps my code clear, but is there a chance of losing the `WakeLock` when I call self-written methods?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the "self-written methods" do not fork a thread or otherwise do something asynchronously, you are safe.

Comment: One more question: Is there a maximum time for a method to execute in?

Comment: @Merlin: Well, eventually the sun will burn out or go nova or something. I'd try to wrap up before then. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Calling a method does not mean you leave `doWakefulWork` and it ends. It's more like copying the method's lines of code to the calling method.

So this here

```
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent arg0) {
    exampleMethod();

    exampleMethod2();
}

private void exampleMethod() {
    exampleMethod2();
    exampleMethod2();
}

private void exampleMethod2() {
    print("Hello");
}
```

does exactly the same thing as this here

```
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent arg0) {
    { // exampleMethod()
        { // exampleMethod2()
            print("Hello");
        }
        { // exampleMethod2()
            print("Hello");
        }
    }

    { // exampleMethod2()
        print("Hello");
    }
}
```

or without all the braces

```
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent arg0) {
    print("Hello");
    print("Hello");
    print("Hello");
}
```

So you never leave `doWakefulWork` when calling a method and the `WakeLock` can't go away therefore.

Comment: @AkhilJain I think what I tried to says is that a direct method call can not be asynchronous and could also be written inlined into the calling method. And you don't need "self-written methods" to initiate asynchronous things that outlive the wakelock.